# Golang remove string prefix when unmarshalling JSON

Tags: go, unmarshalling

In my json data structure I have a string that can have a prefix. When unmarshalling JSON, is it possible to have a function to remove that prefix? I am looking into custom JSON unmarshalling in golang and trying to leverage that.

For example. The payload can be either of the following

```
{
  "id": "urn:uuid:1234567890"
}

{
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```

When I do `JSON.unmarshall(data, &struct)` I'd like the unmarshall function to handle removing the `urn:uuid` prefix from the string if it is there so the struct will always have the value `1234567890` for `id`.

Comment: You can do that by making the `id` field of the `struct` have a custom type and  have that type implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface. Just make sure the `id` field is actually exported or else it won't get decoded.

Comment: Postprocess. basically undoable during unmarshaling if you do not provid your own unmarshaler (too much).

Comment: If you're looking into customizing unmarshalling, you must already know it's possible, so... what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm having some problems actually implementing the custom unmarshalling. I was trying to do it on the whole struct itself. But it as @mkopriva mentioned, its supposed to be done on the id field itself.

Comment: @Sakib something like this https://play.golang.org/p/J6iadpsTgO

Comment: yeah that is what I am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a custom UnmarshalJSON method on the data you need to trim, here is an example implementation, you may need to extend if you have to regex match the start rather than match hard string (or byte array in this case):

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-pK3LHdTss)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

var (
    sampleJSON   = []byte(`{"id": "urn:uuid:1234567890"}`)
    prefixToTrim = []byte(`urn:uuid:`)
)

type IDField string

type Data struct {
    ID IDField `json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    d := &Data{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(sampleJSON, d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(d.ID)
}

// UnmarshalJSON provides custom unmarshalling to trim `urn:uuid:` prefix from IDField
func (id *IDField) UnmarshalJSON(rawIDBytes []byte) error {

    // trim quotes and prefix
    trimmedID := bytes.TrimPrefix(bytes.Trim(rawIDBytes, `"`), prefixToTrim)

    // convert back to id field & assign
    *id = IDField(trimmedID)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This is a really sleek solution. My problem is that now when I'm using `ID` as string, I need to do conversion `string(ID)`. Is there a way around it?